# Google Cloud Functions include Brew dependency

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Since Google AppEngine 2.7 doesn't allow for 3rd party libraries using C lib extensions, I've been looking for alternatives to set up a backend simliar to what is shown in the repo: https://github.com/jpf/okta-pysaml2-example. It is basically saml for python that will run alongside my GAE standard environment.

Google cloud functions seems to almost be a great fit but I don't see a way to install Brew dependencies. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to install system-level dependencies for Cloud Functions or the App Engine Standard environments (2.7 or 3.7).

Instead, you'll need to [create an App Engine Flex custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/), and manually define a `Dockerfile` which installs the dependencies, with a line something like this:

```
RUN apt-get install libffi-dev libxmlsec1 libssl-dev
```

Also note that the App Engine platform is Ubuntu, so you would use the `apt` package manager, not `brew` (which is for macOS).

Comment: thank you, i have done just this and it turned out to be pretty easy